# phantomjs vs selenium performance

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I've been using selenium in python to drive phantomjs. The problem is that it is quite slow.

I'm beginning to think that it is selenium that is slow, not the core phantomjs functionality of emulating a browser, Javascript and all.

Is there a more direct way to drive phantom that is faster?

Comment: Well what exactly is slow? Give us examples.

Comment: I don't have benchmarks, but 1-2 minutes per page just to load page, select 10-15 elements by css selector, and grab a few links seems quite slow to me.

Comment: it's not selenium that is slow.. selenium goes as fast as all your hardware goes (and web service). maybe it's the machine you're running on?

Comment: 8gb, dual core Mac OSX, so that doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: Is it slow on all URLs?  e.g. if you load a very simple URL like google.com, it still takes a long time?

Comment: What pages are loading?

Comment: There is definitely a "more direct way" to drive PhatomJS. Did you try the docs? http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html

Answer (score 0):

set load images equals to false , which will definitely help you to increase the speed of phantomJS.